# Flutter devtools throw error immediately when it's open

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-devtools

I have an application that has some RenderFlex overflowed issues, so as everyone facing problems like this, I tried to open the Flutter dev tools.

the is debugging fine with those Renderflow issues, but just when **I open the dev tools, immediately it throws this error.**

[image]

```
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 5832 pos 12: '_renderObject != null': MultiChildRenderObjectElement unmounted)
```

I don't know even where exactly the problem, or what exactly cause this

I will be thankful for any ideas

Comment: Is it your flutter version and vscode up to date?

Comment: yes I am using Flutter 3.3.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4f9d92fbbd (9 weeks ago) • 2022-09-06 17:54:53 -0700
Engine • revision 3efdf03e73
Tools • Dart 2.18.0 • DevTools 2.15.0

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this query by adding exception breakpoint from VScode. It will give you exact line of code, which triggered this error. So far this query is related to widget binding, you are binding widget before page is mounted.